# Update MediaStyle notification of a foreground service without POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission via NotificationManager.notify in Android 13

Tags: android, foreground-service, android-13, android-notification.mediastyle

My app targets API 33 ([Android 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_13)), and runs a foreground service to play online music.

Once the notification is started via `startForeground(notification_Id, notification)`, I can update the notification via `notificationManager.notify(notification_Id, notification)`. However, Android Studio tells me that the `android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission is missing.

Even though I include that permission in the AndroidManifest, I don't need to ask the user to grant the permission to update the notification.

Is this method of updating the notification is valid or is it a security hole?
Obviously the method works, but I have not found any reference in the documentation of Android 13+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even though I include that permission in the AndroidManifest, I don't need to ask the user to grant the permission to update the notification.

> Can anyone confirm if this method of updating the notification is valid or is it a security hole? Obviously the method works but I have not found any reference in the documentation of Android 13+

That's fine. No security hole. There are some exemptions that do not require the `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission. According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#exemptions-media-sessions), notifications related to media sessions are exempt from this behavior change. `MediaStyle` uses media session to build up the notification.

Comment: Thanks for your reply János, I already knew that starting with Andorid 13, when a MediadiaSession is created through a foreground service the system automatically displays a notification.
My question is focused on whether it is legal to update that notification using `notificationManager.notify` instead of updating the `MetadataMediasession` data.

Answer (score 0):

`POST_NOTIFICATION` permission provides the end-user the ability to  decide which notifications are of significance to him/her. For updating the notification, you don't require any additional permission, just as you could do before. However, it seems like you aren't using the MediaPack3 for managing playback,because as per the documentation, [Notifications related to media sessions are exempt from this behavior change](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#exemptions-media-sessions).